# GUI Software Design Pattern to manage multiple widgets during runtime

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, design-patterns, widget

Does anybody knows a software pattern for handeling multiple widgets states/visibility during runntime?

The problem is: 
An application has about 50 different docking widgets. Depending on the state of the application, some of the docking widgets should be visible and some not.

We are working with C++ and Qt and therefore using the model/view/controller pattern.

I m interested in any architectural idea or any pattern helping to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you have many states I think it's good to use the [Qt State Machine Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html). It can be used to effectively embed the elements and semantics of statecharts in Qt applications. It integrates with Qt's meta-object system; for example, transitions between states can be triggered by signals, and states can be configured to set properties and invoke methods on QObjects. So you can have have different states which configure and set properties for the widgets.